# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'save' pops up in save folder

Tags: arcpy

I am facing this error time and again when I am try to read my img rasters and running a conditional statement. I am new to Python. The code ran for one raster that is without for loop but not later. Here is the code:

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\libpub\Desktop\try"
arcpy.CheckOutExtension('Spatial')

rasterlist = arcpy.ListRasters()
for raster in rasterlist:
    out1 = Con(('Raster')>0.2, 1, 0)
    print out1
    out1.save("C:\Users\libpub\Desktop\try")

print "done!"
```

Comment: welcome to GIS SE! Please use this guide to indent block you code: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks Also, please post the exact error message you are receiving.

Comment: Add an r to the path  `out1.save(r"...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `arcpy.ListRasters` function returns a list of the raster names in your workspace. The `Con` function, in the format you are using, requires an input Raster object which can be created with:

```
rast = Raster('raster_name')
```

If you change `out1 = Con(('Raster')>0.2, 1, 0)` to `out1 = Con(Raster(raster)>0.2, 1, 0)` you should find it works. This is shown in the `Con` [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/con-.htm) in code example 1.